Acting on checkbox selections in urwid [python]
I have a very simple application I'm writing in urwid - to make the clearing of docker images from my machine much, much easier.
The code [below] essentially creates a list of images on disk (as docker images does), with a checkbox to allow selection.
The idea is to allow the coder to select a bunch of images to delete without having to do docker rmi <cut'n'paste_id> <cut'n'paste_id> <cut'n'paste_id> <cut'n'paste_id> <cut'n'paste_id> for 10 minutes.
I've figured out I can dump the handling of the keypress stuff in unhandled, and I'll probably use the python docker Client again to remove the images.
The question is, though.... how do I get the list of checked items in the list for the Client to remove?
[I accept I may be approaching this badly, and guidance will be read]
Code:
import docker
import urwid

def get_images() -> list:
    client = docker.from_env()

    images = client.images.list()

    images_list = list()
    for image in images:
        id = image.short_id[7:]
        created = image.attrs['Created'].split('.')
        if len(image.tags):
            for i in image.tags:
                images_list.append([id, i, created[0]])
        else:
            images_list.append([id, '<none>', created[0]])
    return images_list

def main():
    images_list = get_images()

    listbox_content = list()
    for image in images_list:
        row = urwid.Columns(
            [
                urwid.CheckBox(image[0]),
                ('weight', 2, urwid.Text(image[1])),
                urwid.Text(image[2]),
            ]
        )
        listbox_content.append(row)

    text_header = "Docker Image Manager - UP / DOWN / PAGE UP / PAGE DOWN scroll.  F8 exits."
    header = urwid.AttrMap(urwid.Text(text_header), "header")
    listbox = urwid.ListBox(urwid.SimpleListWalker(listbox_content))
    scrollable = urwid.ScrollBar(
        listbox,
        trough_char=urwid.ScrollBar.Symbols.LITE_SHADE,
    )
    palette = [
        ("body", "black", "light gray", "standout"),
        ("reverse", "light gray", "black"),
        ("header", "white", "dark red", "bold"),
        ("important", "dark blue", "light gray", ("standout", "underline")),
        ("editfc", "white", "dark blue", "bold"),
        ("editbx", "light gray", "dark blue"),
        ("editcp", "black", "light gray", "standout"),
        ("bright", "dark gray", "light gray", ("bold", "standout")),
        ("buttn", "black", "dark cyan"),
        ("buttnf", "white", "dark blue", "bold"),
    ]
    frame = urwid.Frame(urwid.AttrMap(scrollable, "body"), header=header)
    # use appropriate Screen class
    if urwid.display.web.is_web_request():
        screen = urwid.display.web.Screen()
    else:
        screen = urwid.display.raw.Screen()


    def unhandled(key: str | tuple[str, int, int, int]) -> None:
        if key == "f8":
            raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
        # if key == 'del':
        #    delete all selected images
        # if key == 'f9':
        #    do some form as `docker builder prune`
        # can we do a "delete all" in some easy manner?


    urwid.MainLoop(frame, palette, screen, unhandled_input=unhandled).run()

def setup():
    urwid.display.web.set_preferences("Urwid Tour")
    # try to handle short web requests quickly
    if urwid.display.web.handle_short_request():
        return

    main()


if __name__ == "__main__" or urwid.display.web.is_web_request():
    setup()

Addendum

Docker Desktop would have been the logical tool for this, however [on Ubuntu] it does not appear to actually list any of my images.... and gets in the way of my habitual command-line interactions
I'm fairly surprised someone's not already done this.... I can build up a few hundred GB of images fairly quickly when I'm developing cluster-based apps.

